# How to define a function whose input is a column name?

Tags: python, function, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to define a function who has 2 input. A dataset and a column name.
Unfortunately I can't pass the column name because I get error:

```
def def(df,ColName):
    
    

       F.instr('ColName', s)) for s in stop_words]),
        # If no stop words found, get the whole string
        F.length('ColName') + 1)
    ).selectExpr('trim(substring(ColName, 1, idx-1)) ColName')
    
    return Transitions
```

When I call the function:

```
Transitions= Collecting_transition(Originaltitles,originaltitle)
```

I get error:

> name 'originaltitle' is not defined

I tried to pass string `originaltitle` but again because of this part `).selectExpr('trim(substring(ColName, 1, idx-1)) ColName')`  I get another error.

Comment: You haven't assigned `originaltitle` as anything. Try `originaltitle = "NewTitle"` before you call the function

Comment: What is the other error?

Comment: @foxyblue I did `originaltitle = "NewTitle"` but I got this error: `cannot resolve '`ColName`' given input columns: [originaltitle];; `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `ColName` variable inside the function, not the string `'ColName'`.

```
def fun(df, ColName):

    Transitions = df.withColumn('idx',
    F.coalesce(
        # Get the smallest index of a stop word in the string
        F.least(*[F.when(F.instr(ColName, s) != 0, F.instr(ColName, s)) for s in stop_words]),
        # If no stop words found, get the whole string
        F.length(ColName) + 1)
    ).selectExpr(f'trim(substring({ColName}, 1, idx-1)) {ColName}')
    
    return Transitions

Transitions = fun(Originaltitles, 'originaltitle')
```